# Default Values C++11, compiler to compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, default-value

### Question 1:

How can you tell the default value of a variable? That is (if my vocabulary is wrong) the value of a variables before it is assigned?

### Question 2:

How does this differ between compilers?

### Question 3:

Is there a better way to default values?

### Question 4:

And finally, are there other exceptions to this rule?

### Example code:

```
bool foolean;
int fintoo;
double fooble;
char charafoo;
```

What would these be by default compiler to compiler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In all versions of C++, all the variables in your question will be zero-initialized (statically) if they're declared at namespace scope. In all other cases, they will have garbage values if left uninitialized.

Note that a garbage value is anything which is at the memory location where the variable is defined — it is just a pattern of 0s and 1s. *Such values shouldn't be read by your program, else your code will invoke undefined behaviour*.

In C++11, if you write these as local variables (or namespace variables):

```
bool foolean {};
int fintoo {};
double fooble {};
char charafoo {};
```

They're default-initialized which means zero in this case (as they are built-types).

Comment: What are the garbage values? Are they just what 0's and 1's were previously in that memory location?

Comment: Cool, never heard about that namespace thing. Always thought that uninitialized variables always contain random values. (Just what the allocated memory contains)

Comment: @JimHurley: It could be anything; it is just a pattern of 0s and 1s. Such values shouldn't be read by your program, else your code will invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is a very descriptive, speedy, and helpful answer, thank you very much. I had no idea about the namespace thing. This could help a lot of people.

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee as to what the garbage values will be! Generally, they will be the values which were last stored in this location but they can very well be changed in some way. The main reasons for this behavior are performance and, more importantly, to allow constructing objects in specific locations to deliberately pick up the underlying values, e.g., for memory mapped I/O.

Comment: All of these wonderful comments should be added to the question.

Comment: Note that the `static` keyword has the same storage effect as `using namespace` (Edited)

Comment: @JimHurley: Not exactly "same". It is same as far as "storage" is concerned. But it also has effect on the linkage which is different from namespace. `static` variables defined at namespace scope has internal linkage, while non-static variables defined at namespace scope has external linkage.

Answer (score 1):

If a variable is automatic (that is, a non-`static` variable local to a function, or a member thereof), there is no default. From pratical perspective, the variable is allocated on stack, and what's there on the stack (probably leftover from a previous function call) will become the value of the variable.

Also, some compilers add code to initialize the stack frame to a well-known value in debug mode. That lets you easily see that a variable hasn't been initialized while debugging.

If a variable is static (declared in namespace scope, or with the `static` keyword in a function), the default is zero.